# Beamer with Tikz graphs

Tags: beamer, tikz-styles, pause

Following [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/173132/distances-between-nodes-nodes-and-arrows) question of mine, I now need to make a presentation using Beamer.

If you look at the plot below, it has some values on the arrows namely p1, 1-p1, ... I want to put the graph structure first and then when pressing the arrow key get the values showing one by one.
Just writing `\pause` in front of the nodes doesn't work, that would have been too simple. I don't know how to make it happen, anyone help?

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows,positioning}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\begin{tikzpicture}[->,>=stealth',shorten >=1pt,auto,node distance=2.5cm,
                thick,main node/.style={rectangle,draw,font=\sffamily\Large    \bfseries}]  

\node[main node] (1) {1};
\node[main node] (2) [below = of 1] {2};
\node[main node] (3) [below = of 2] {3};
\node[main node,draw = none] (4) [right = 2in of 1] {$\varnothing$};
\node[main node,draw = none] (5) [right = 2in of 2] {$\varnothing$};
\node[main node,draw = none] (6) [right = 2in of 3] {$\varnothing$};

\path[every node/.style={font=\sffamily\small}]
(1) edge node [left] {$p_1$} (2)
    edge node [above] {$1-p_1$} (4)
(2) edge node [left] {$p_2$} (3)
    edge node [above] {$1-p_2$} (5)
(3)   edge node [above] {$1-p_3$} (6);
\path[draw,every node/.style={font=\sffamily\small}]
(3.west) -- ([xshift=-2cm]3.west) -- ([xshift=-2cm]1.west) node [midway,left] {$p_3$} -- (1.west); 
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use `visible on` style (see [Mindmap tikzpicture in beamer (reveal step by step)](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/55849/1952)). This one is used in code below but there are some other options not far away provided by [Matthew Leingang](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/6155/1952), [Claudio Fiandrino](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/84608/1952), [Qrrbrbirlbel](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/84538/1952) or [Gonzalo Medina](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/175100/1952) just to mention some of them.

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows,positioning}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\tikzset{
    invisible/.style={opacity=0,text opacity=0},
    visible on/.style={alt=#1{}{invisible}},
    alt/.code args={<#1>#2#3}{%
      \alt<#1>{\pgfkeysalso{#2}}{\pgfkeysalso{#3}} % \pgfkeysalso doesn't change the path
    },
}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\begin{tikzpicture}[->,>=stealth',shorten >=1pt,auto,node distance=2.5cm,
                thick,main node/.style={rectangle,draw,font=\sffamily\Large    \bfseries}]  

\node[main node] (1) {1};
\node[main node] (2) [below = of 1] {2};
\node[main node] (3) [below = of 2] {3};
\node[main node,draw = none] (4) [right = 2in of 1] {$\varnothing$};
\node[main node,draw = none] (5) [right = 2in of 2] {$\varnothing$};
\node[main node,draw = none] (6) [right = 2in of 3] {$\varnothing$};

\path[every node/.style={font=\sffamily\small}]
(1) edge node [left, visible on=<2->] {$p_1$} (2)
    edge node [above, visible on=<2->] {$1-p_1$} (4)
(2) edge node [left, visible on=<3->] {$p_2$} (3)
    edge node [above, visible on=<3->] {$1-p_2$} (5)
(3)   edge node [above, visible on=<4->] {$1-p_3$} (6);
\path[draw,every node/.style={font=\sffamily\small}]
(3.west) -- ([xshift=-2cm]3.west) -- ([xshift=-2cm]1.west) node [midway,left, visible on=<4->] {$p_3$} -- (1.west); 
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Works well thanks. I had to fiddle around with `visible on=<2->` and set the value to be 5 and above for it to work. Does this represent the nth click? And how can I know apart from trial and error method?

Comment: @TAllieri: Yes the number represent the nth click. `<2->` means it will be shown from second in advance, `<2>` only on second frame, `<2-4>` on second, third and foorth frame, ... If you previously plan how the labels are shown you know the frame number. In any case I've included some other answer which can help you.

Comment: Apparently now there's the [`aobs-tikz` package](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/aobs-tikz) for the purpose of combining TikZ and beamer overlay

Comment: @KevinC Yes the aobs-tikz package was the result of Claudio's answer linked in my answer.